# AWK-how to improve this regular expression?

Tags: awk

I have an example:

```
pic@pic:~$ echo ",article{gjn2010jucs, Author =   {Grzegorz J. Nalepa}, " | awk '{gsub(/[^,],.*/,""); print }' 
,article{gjn2010juc 
pic@pic:~$
```

How to improve the regular expression to get the result:

```
,article{gjn2010jucs
```

Comment: You should be a lot more specific about your requirements here.

Comment: What additional information do I need? I'm talking about this particular case.

Comment: `awk -F, '{printf ",%s\n",$2}'`?

Comment: @twalberg, Exactly the result I want to print. I just want to do it right regular expression that will remove `, Author = {Grzegorz J. Nalepa},`

Comment: If you're specifically trying to get rid of `Author ... ,`, `sed -e 's/ *Author[^,]*, */ /'` would strip that part out. If what you're trying to remove isn't always `Author = ...`, though, that won't work.

Comment: @twalberg, The regular expression must be written on the basis of "," because the field "Author" is just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your looking to improve your regular expression: you will need to use capture groups, and these are not features available in `sub()` or `gsub()`. You will need to use `gensub()`.
You can read more about string manipulation functions [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html).

I would use `gensub()` like this:

```
awk '{ print gensub(/(,[^,]+).*/,"\\1", "g") }'
```

Testing:

```
echo ",article{gjn2010jucs, Author =   {Grzegorz J. Nalepa}, " | awk '{ print gensub(/(,[^,]+).*/,"\\1", "g") }'
```

Results:

```
,article{gjn2010jucs
```

Comment: Thank you for a good solution. Work in gawk, but it does not work with mawk.

Comment: @Tedee12345: You are correct. `mawk` doesn't come complete with certain functions including `gensub()` unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, instead of finding stuff to discard, find stuff to keep: keep the first comma and all subsequent non-comma characters:

```
gawk 'match($0, /^,[^,]+/, ary) {print ary[0]}'
```

mawk update:

```
mawk 'match($0, /^,[^,]+/) {print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)}'
```

Comment: Thank you for a good solution. Work in gawk, but it does not work with mawk.